# How can I treat strings read from SQL as verbatim?

Tags: c#, sql, regex

I'm working on a virus / ransomware early warning system for our facility that compares filenames and paths collected from a FileSystemMonitor against a list of regular expressions from an SQL database.

The issue I am having is with C# escaping my regex expressions as they are read from the SQL server.

For example:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Filters ORDER BY Sequence ASC", sqlServer);
SqlDataReader reader = null;
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
filter temp;

while (reader.Read())
{
    temp.dir = @reader["Folder"].ToString().Trim();
    temp.file = @reader["Filter"].ToString().Trim();

    if (!temp.file.Equals(""))
    {
        filterList.Add(temp);
    }
}
```

If the SQL field `Filter` contains the valid regex `.*\.scr$`, `temp.filter` ends up with the contents `.*\\.scr$` which causes the regex match to be missed.

How can I maintain the verbatim state of my regex when read from SQL?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Where are you seeing the extra backslash?  If it's in debug, that's because it shows the escape sequences there.

Comment: How are you verifying that your string contains `.*\\.scr$`? Setting breakpoints and using the inspector to see the value of the variable will always show escape characters.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't just looking to the debug window? It shows the strings escaped there, but in fact they don't contain those escape characters.

Comment: Yes, I am looking at debug info.  I had assumed that it would show the exact contents of the strings... sounds like it doesn't.

Comment: @RussellNash it actually does show the exact content of the string as stored in memory when you think about it.

Comment: @user1666620 That does make sense actually, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to verify that this question has been resolved.  Including `@` in front of the reader commands is having the desired effect, it's just that I was viewing the strings via the debug environment which was confusing me to think otherwise.

Thanks for everyone's input!  Was going to upvote the helpful comments, but it looks like I don't have enough rep yet for that.